# Null pointer Exception in Junit using Spring Boot CRUD

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mybatis

Below is my JUnit test code where I'm getting `Null pointer Exception`

```
public class MybatisApplicationTests {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    @Test
    public void deleteUserByIdTest() {
        UserController uc = new UserController();
    Long id = 3L;
    assertEquals(1,uc.deleteUserById(id));

    }
```

Below is my controller `UserService.java`

```
@DeleteMapping("/deleteUserById/{id}")
public int deleteUserById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    System.out.println("delete meth called");
    userService.deleteUserById(id);
    return 1;
}
```

And below is my ServiceImpl.java

```
@Override
public int deleteUserById(Long id) {
    System.out.println("delete meth service called");
    userMapper.deleteUserById(id);
    return 1;
}
```

I've tried in all possible ways, but I'm getting `NullPointerException` as an error. Help me to resolve the error & thanks in advance.

Comment: Share the error message that shown in console.

Comment: Below is the error message
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.naveen.controller.UserController.deleteUserById(UserController.java:54) at com.naveen.MybatisApplicationTests.deleteUserByIdTest(MybatisApplicationTests.java:31) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

Comment: You did not use `@Autowired` before `UserController uc;`  in your `MybatisApplicationTests` class.

Comment: @MazedulIslam I've added Autowired to UserController uc, still same Exception occurs,

Comment: what is there in this line `UserController.java:54`?

Comment: @MazedulIslam userService.deleteUserById(id);

Comment: For what i see you have autowired UserController and then you overriden it with `this.uc = new UserController();`

Comment: @MaciejNiedźwiedź   I was trying to resolve that NullPointerException there. If you help me to resolve, it'll be much helpful.

Comment: You should just autowire the UserController instead of using new operator as the services within that needs to be autowired.

Comment: Can you provide us with configuration of Spring context you are using?

Comment: @deepakchethan Yeah, You're right. issue resolved now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ideally autowire the UserController instead of using new operator as the services/beans within that controller needs to be autowired.

```
public class MybatisApplicationTests {
    @Autowired
    UserController uc;
    @Test
    public void deleteUserByIdTest() {
       Long id = 3L;
       assertEquals(1,uc.deleteUserById(id));
    }
```

But if this is a unit test, it is better to mock the inner bean functionality altogether by using Inject mocks and mock.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MybatisApplicationTests {

    @InjectMocks
    UserController uc;
    @Mock
    UserService userService;
    @Test
    public void deleteUserByIdTest() {
       Long id = 3L;
       assertEquals(1,uc.deleteUserById(id));
    }
```

Comment: So, what this inject mock and mock will do here?

Comment: Basically instead of using "real" beans or services. We use mock beans that mock the service functionality. We can isolate and test  the controllers code alone assuming that the bean is unit tested separately. But its all upto your requirements.